# Browse vector with std::vector<std::pair < > >

Tags: c++, oop, vector, iterator, std-pair

I have the following  vector:

```
std::vector< std::pair<std::string,bool > > myvec;
```

How can i browse and print elements of my vector with iterators?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What is your problem?

```
typedef std::vector<std::pair<std::string, bool> > vector_type;
for (vector_type::const_iterator pos = myvec.begin();
     pos != myvec.end(); ++pos)
{
   std::cout << pos->first << " " << pos->second << std::endl;
}
```

or you can use `std::for_each` with some functor.

Comment: The overload won't work:  both of the operand types are in the `std` namespace, so the overload would need to be placed in the `std` namespace.  But, you aren't allowed to declare overloads in the `std` namespace.

Comment: You defined `typedef` as `vector` and defined `const_iterator` When i changed my code same you i get error, Because i'm using `find_if`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create iterator, pointing to the first element of the vector (syntax: `Container::iterator iter = myContainer.begin()`)
2. in a `for`-loop, iterate through all elements ( `iterator` has `operator++`; the end condition is - check if the iterator has reached the `end` of your container, like: `iter != myContainer.end()`)
3. Iterators are like pointers, to reach it's members, use `operator->`.
4. `std::pair` is like a struct with two fields - `first` and `second`, so you can print a vector's element like: `iter->first` and `iter->second`.